# How could a "SECURITY DEFINER" function in PG be insecure with an improper search_path?

Tags: postgresql, functions

The PG docs provides [this example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) of a properly written security definer function with a search_path:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_password(uname TEXT, pass TEXT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE passed BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
        SELECT  (pwd = $2) INTO passed
        FROM    pwds
        WHERE   username = $1;

        RETURN passed;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
    SECURITY DEFINER
    -- Set a secure search_path: trusted schema(s), then 'pg_temp'.
    SET search_path = admin, pg_temp;
```

I don't understand this part:

> But without the SET clause, or with a SET clause mentioning only
>   admin, the function could be subverted by creating a temporary table
>   named pwds.

If `admin.pwds` exists and `search_path` is set to `admin` only, how is it even possible to create a temporary table, `pwds`, maliciously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `pg_temp` is not present in `search_path` at all, then the temp scheme is always searched first, i.e. as if it were implicitly prepended to `search_path`.

The only way to prevent it from being searched first is to give it an explicit presence in `search_path`.